# Show only countdown in timeout command

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I need to run the timeout command without the message `press a key to continue...`

I tried the command `timeout /t 10 > null` but it doesn't work for me because it strips the message and countdown together.

Default command:

```
@echo off
echo Wait...
timeout /t 10
exit
```

Result:

```
Wait...
Waiting 9 seconds, press a key to continue...
```

What I need:

```
Wait...
Waiting 9 seconds
```

How to make the timeout command show only the countdown without the message `press a key to continue ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the countdown timer, you should accept @Hackoo post.  They answered first with more or less the same answer without the actual 10 .. 9 .. 8 .. etc.

If you do want an actual countdown timer, it gets tricky without the use of ANSI escape sequences to position the cursor.

Here is a simple way to do it by clearing the screen each time (you might not like it).

```bat
@echo off
set countdown=10

:timer_loop
cls
echo Wait...
echo Waiting %countdown% seconds...

timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul

set /a countdown=%countdown% -1
if %countdown% NEQ 0 goto :timer_loop

echo Timer complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

In batch is `nul` and not `null`

---

```bat
@echo off
echo Wait...
timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul
exit
```

futher reading [timeout /?](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)

---

***EDIT :*** Show only a simulation of Progress Bar without the message `press a key to continue...`

---

May be this dosen't answer the OP's Question, but if someone else wants something like a simulation of a progress bar why not ?

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Show only a simulation of Progress Bar without the message press a key to continue ...
CHCP 65001>nul
set countdown=10
echo. & Call :PSColor "Please Wait a while ... Working is in Progress ..." DarkCyan \n
:timer_loop
REM Remark : I got "◘" by pressing [Alt] + [8]
REM (the actual symbol may vary depending upon codepage).
<nul set /p "_s=◘"
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
set /a countdown-=1
if %countdown% GEQ 0 goto :timer_loop
echo. & Call :PSColor "Timer is completed." Cyan \n
Pause & Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------
 :PSColor <String> <Color> <NewLine>
 If /I [%3] EQU [\n] (
    Powershell Write-Host "`0%~1" -ForegroundColor %2
 ) Else (
    Powershell Write-Host "`0%~1" -ForegroundColor %2 -NoNewLine
 )
 Exit /B
 ::---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: but this doesnt show the timeout as the OP specified

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas He said ***I need to run the timeout command without the message*** `press a key to continue...`

Comment: He said "***Show only countdown***" perhaps I misunderstood this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Señor CMasMas's answer, but using a trick to overwrite one line instead of clearing the whole screen:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM create a CariageReturn:
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
set countdown=10
:timer_loop
<nul set /p ".=Waiting %countdown% seconds...  !cr!"
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
set /a countdown-=1
if %countdown% GEQ 0 goto :timer_loop
echo Timer complete.           (enough spaces here to overwrite the timer line)
```

Comment: The first code of Mr. Hackoo, it wasn't what I wanted because it removes the message and the countdown... the second code, with the progress bar, is pretty cool but I have to change the encoding type of the batch when I save the code and , as in my language (Brazilian Portuguese), there are many words with special characters, these words have different codes. The answers from Stephan and @Señor CMasMas met my needs better. As Mr. Señor CMasMas replied before Mr. Stephan, I will vote for Mr. Señor CMasMas.

Comment: This is a cool trick @Stephan !! :)  I didn't think of that!